# How to add one to one relation field in a existing model through South migration

Tags: django, django-south

I already have a model,

```
class ModelA( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField ( max_length = 255, blank = False )
```

and i have many entries in it. Now i want to add a field in it, which is

```
user = models.OneToOneField( User )
```

How do i add this field into `ModelA`? Is there any solution other than deleting all previous entries?

Comment: And what is the problem? `--auto` doesn't work?

Comment: `--auto` works but asks for default value for previous entries?

Comment: `user` field is `unique=True` and `null=False`

Comment: If you want to delete all the previous entries, just delete them before migrating. :-)

Comment: You can add null=True to OneToOneField

Comment: @szaman `OneToOneField` is `unique=True` so more than one null entries in db are not allowed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use this pattern:

1. Add "user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)" to your Model (don't remove the "name" field)
2. run 'manage.py schemamigration --auto'. And apply the migration. Now there are two columns in your table.
3. Now create a datamigration. Edit the file: you need to loop over all objects in your model and set the user field.
4. Remove the "name=models.CharField" from the model.py file. And remove the null=True from the user field.
5. run 'manage.py schemamigration --auto'. And apply the migration

BTW, if you use OneToOneField() without null=True, you can set primary_key=True on this field, since it must be unique. But I don't know if south can handle this migration.

Comment: after step 5, when am going to migrate, migration asks to add default value for user because its going to NOT NULL from NULL state. So what will be the default value? empty string doesn't work :(

Comment: Try 0, or edit the create schema migration file and give a default of 0 there.

Comment: The exact same approach works for Django migrations (without South), with 'python manage.py makemigrations' for steps 2 and 5.  Thank you!